# How do I get sass to work in Coda?

Tags: sass

I have been to Git hub and I do not know how to get sass to work from the file there.  I am not too good with the terminal.  Can someone help with this?  Thank you

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @sarnold there is this link https://github.com/Brajeshwar/Sass.mode what do I do when I get there?

Comment: Did you `git clone` the repository to your `~/Library/Application Support/Coda/Modes` directory yet?

Comment: That is the problem.  I have no idea what that means or how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkdir -p "~/Library/Application Support/Coda/Modes"
cd !$
git clone https://github.com/Brajeshwar/Sass.mode.git
```

The `!$` is a `bash(1)` history-command that uses the last argument from the previous command. Neat little trick, but not necessary. Feel free to re-paste the entire directory again if you rather see explicit commands.

Comment: Is this what I type exactly in the Terminal?  If you could format your response in a 123 instruction I think I could understand.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd just be putting a `1.` in front of the first command, a `2.` in front of the second command, and a `3.` in front of the third command. :)

Comment: @sarnod So I would make a directory 1.? mkdir -p "~/Library/Application Support/Coda/Modes"
Then I go to the directory 2.? cd !$
and 3.? git clone https://github.com/Brajeshwar/Sass.mode.git  What is the -p? and do I need the quotations?

Comment: The `-p` will create all the directories in the hierarchy, not only the final directory. (`mkdir(1)` without the `-p` will only create the last directory listed.) You do need the quotations, because the spaces will appear to be command separators to the shell -- the quotes will tell the shell to treat it as a single argument, which will be passed to the `mkdir(1)` command as a single parameter.

Comment: Ok I will try and let you know.  Thanks.

Comment: I put the first 2 and they seem to work,  then I put git clone https://github.com/Brajeshwar/Sass.mode.git and it says git: comand not found..

Comment: Ah, no `git` installed yet. You'll need to [install `git` before continuing](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3). More details about `git` are on http://git-scm.com/

Comment: Ok.  Installed Git. Ran and this is what I got: graham-dunns-imac:~ grahamdunn$ mkdir -p "~/Library/Application Support/Coda/Modes"
graham-dunns-imac:~ grahamdunn$ git clone https://github.com/Brajeshwar/Sass.mode.git
Cloning into 'Sass.mode'...
remote: Counting objects: 115, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (78/78), done.
remote: Total 115 (delta 36), reused 106 (delta 31)
Receiving objects: 100% (115/115), 25.83 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (36/36), done.
graham-dunns-imac:~ grahamdunn$  Did I get it?

Comment: I think you forgot to change directory first -- you probably unpacked the `Sass.mode` repository into your home directory. `mv ~/Sass.mode "~/Library/Application Support/Coda/Modes"` should fix that.